# replace items in a list with items in a another list

Tags: list-manipulation, replacement

Suppose I have a list `A={x1,x2,x3}`, a list `B={3,4,5}`, and a function `f[x]=x1+x2+x3`. Is there a simple way to create a replacement rule `R` such that I can do a `f[x]/.R` to get `3+4+5`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple way: [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Thread.html).

```
x1 + x2 + x3 /. Thread[A -> B]
```

Other ways to create the list of replacement rules include

```
Rule @@@ Transpose[{A, B}]
MapThread[Rule, {A, B}]
Inner[Rule, A, B, List]
```

Or less obvious

```
Function[,Rule[##],Listable][A,B]
```