# ReplaceAll with a list of parameters

Tags: replacement, syntax

Trying to `ReplaceAll` with a list of parameters, but I can't see how to do it properly:

```
(a + b + c) /. {{a, b, c} -> {1, 2, 3}}
(a + b + c) /. {a, b, c} -> {1, 2, 3}
```

I would like to get the answer = 6, but instead I get

```
a + b + c
```

What is the correct way to pass these values as a list? I know I can do this:

```
(a + b + c) /. {a->1, b->2, c->3}
```

but I have a very long list to pass.

Comment: `(a + b + c) /. Thread[{a, b, c} -> {1, 2, 3}]`

Comment: For very long rule lists also look int [Dispatch](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dispatch.html)

Comment: I wonder about the close-reason: If you look up `ReplaceAll` or `Rule` in the docs, or even the tutorial [Transformation Rules and Definitions](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/TransformationRulesAndDefinitions.html), which is the extent of what seems reasonable to expect, you cannot find this problem solved. It's a commonly solved problem (google [`"Thread[vars ->"`](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=%22Thread%5Bvars+-%3E%22+site:mathematica.stackexchange.com&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)), and perhaps...

Comment: ...here's a duplicate: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42224/replace-items-in-a-list-with-items-in-a-another-list

Comment: The solution by @cvgmt works for me. I hadn't spotted the duplicate question. This is a good example of where a more thorough search would have avoided a duplicate post. Also the solutions below are nice use of Inner.

Answer (score 2):

```
keys = {a, b, c};
values = {1, 2, 3}; 
Flatten@Inner[Rule, {keys}, Transpose@{values}, List]
 (* {a -> 1, b -> 2, c -> 3} *)

(a + b + c) /. %
 (* 6 *)
```

Comment: `Inner[Rule, keys, values, List]` also works.